# How to merge 3 tables as one single table in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have 3 tables :

1.company_master

```
  id            com_name        unique_id
   1           stackoverflow      ABCD
   2           google             EFGH
```

2.internal_employee_master

```
  id          employee_name        unique_id
   1           Noah                    ABCD
   2           Liam                    ABCD
   3           William                 ABCD
   4           Benjamin                ABCD
   5           Jacob                   EFGH
```

3.external_employee_master

```
  id    employee_name     unique_id
   1    Elijah             ABCD
   2    Ethan              ABCD
   3    Alexander          EFGH
```

I am having one dynamic select box with all companies and onchange event 
i want all internal and exernal employees of particular employees in single row.
for e.g

if user will select **stackoverflow** from select box user will get all data from `internal_employee_master` and `external_employee_master`:

```
  id          employee_name        unique_id
   1           Noah                    ABCD
   2           Liam                    ABCD
   3           William                 ABCD
   4           Benjamin                ABCD
   1           Elijah                  ABCD
   2           Ethan                   ABCD
```

> how to create query to get above data.and then how can insert this
>   data in one table with identification of who is `internal_employee` or
>   who is `external_employee`. I have only one column `unique_id` in all
>   3 tables.

Comment: You can make use of MySQL UNION to get desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`UNION`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html) to return the combined results of two tables...

```
select id, employee_name, unique_id
    from internal_employee_master
    where unique_id = 'ABCD'
union
select id, employee_name, unique_id
    from external_employee_master
    where unique_id = 'ABCD'
```

Although you may be better combining the two tables and just have some flag to indicate which are internal and which external employees.

If you need to identify the different types of employee, you can add a marker to the rows...

```
select id, employee_name, unique_id, "Internal" as typeOfEmployee
    from internal_employee_master
    where unique_id = 'ABCD'
union
select id, employee_name, unique_id, "External" as typeOfEmployee
    from external_employee_master
    where unique_id = 'ABCD'
```

Comment: thanks for your reply.except add one column in table to add flag is there any other way in query to identify internal or external ..

Comment: Was just adding it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNION CLAUSE`.

```
SELECT employee_name, unique_id FROM internal_employee_master WHERE unique_id = 'ABCD'

UNION

SELECT employee_name, unique_id FROM external_employee_master WHERE unique_id = 'ABCD'
```

The SQL UNION clause/operator is used to combine the results of two or more SELECT statements without returning any duplicate rows.